# Turn list into list of lists using an object attribute

Tags: python

I have a list of objects

```
objects = [<object 1>, <object 2>, <object 3>, <object 4>, <object 5>, <object 5>]
```

Each object has an attribute date (object.date). I would like to split the list into a list of lists where each sublist has only objects with the same date. 
Is there some smart way to do this?
My naive solution is

```
list_of_lists = []
for object in objects:
    success = 0
    for list in list_of_lists:
        if object.date == list[0].date:
            list.append(object)
            success = 1
            break
    if not success:
        list_of_lists.append([object])
```

this does give the correct result, but I am just wondering about an optimal solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby()`:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter
my_lists = [list(g) for _, g in groupby(sorted(objects, key=attrgetter('date')), attrgetter('date'))]
```

Note that if your objects are already sorted by the date attribute, you don't need to sort it.

Based on your need, if you need more performance in terms of runtime speed you can use a dictionary for categorizing the objects:

```
my_dict = {}

for obj in objects:
    my_dict.setdefault(obj.date, []).append(obj) # Don't forget to call the `date` if it's callable
```

Note, if you just want the lists in a categorized form you can get the dictionary values:

```
my_lists = my_dict.values()
```

Comment: You'd need to sort `objects` with `key=attrgetter('date')` first, if it's not already sorted by `date`. `groupby` acts like the GNU util `uniq`; it only groups adjacent entries. Of course, if it's already sorted, then the repeated sort costs little (thanks to `TimSort` optimizing for already sorted lists) and `groupby` will win on performance when the sort is cheap.

Comment: You forgot mention one thing, list should be sorted, otherwise result of groupby will be incorrect in some cases.

Comment: Yep, I was editing the answer, thanks for your attentions.